# Getting a SEGFAULT on an unused symbol

Tags: c, lldb, llvm-clang

I am quite new to C (still) so please be patient if I misunderstood something fundamental

I have a simple program that should read a file as a string, and then split that string into lines - storing the result into n array of strings. When I run the following code however I get a SEGFAULT - using lldb shows that it is occurring on a usage of strlen inside the libsystem_platform.dylib library despite no usages of the function anywhere in my code.

Here is the full FileIOTest.c file:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ENDL "\n"

void read_file(const char* path, char** destination) {
    FILE *file;
    long size_in_bytes;
    
    file = fopen(path, "r");
    
    if(file == NULL) {
        fputs("Requested file is invalid", stderr);
        exit(-1);
    }
    
    fseek(file, 0L, SEEK_END);
    size_in_bytes = ftell(file);
    
    fseek(file, 0L, SEEK_SET);  
    
    fread(*destination, sizeof(char), size_in_bytes, file);
    fclose(file);
}

int main() {
    char* file = calloc(1024, sizeof(char));
    read_file("run", &file);

    char* destination[2048];

    char* token = strtok(file, ENDL);
    for(int i = 0; token != NULL; i++) {
        destination[i] = token;
        token = strtok(NULL, ENDL);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 2048; i++)
        printf("%s", destination[i]);
}
```

I have verified that the file reading works - so there is definitely something wrong with my string splitting code but I can't see what exactly is wrong

Any help is really appreciated!

macOS Catalina 15.4 with lldb version lldb-1103.0.22.10 compiled with clang version clang-1103.0.32.62

Comment: Not much of an answer, but is `calloc(1024, sizeof(char))` enough memory to store your file?

Comment: Why don't you look at the whole call stack instead of just the last function?

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i < 2048; i++)` What if there is less than 2048 tokens?

Comment: @ChrisAkridge the file reading succeeds and can be printed so I don't think there is an issue there :/

Comment: @user253751 Im not entirely sure on how to go about that using lldb - and gdb is broken on Catalina

Comment: @TTG you could google it

Comment: @dxiv no change - and the file is exactly 2048 lines of the letter e

Comment: @TTG Not sure what "no change" means here. If you read 2048 lines in a buffer allocated to be 1024 long, then (a) you will overrun it, (b) it's not nul-terminated where `strtok` assumes it will be, (c) if there are 2048 `\n` newlines and a nul-terminator then `destination` will be overrun, too..

Comment: @dxiv I allocated 2048 lines and iterate through 2048 lines - and even if I switch to 1024 there is no change

Comment: this: `char* file` says it is a pointer to char. so passing the address of `file` to the sub function is an error because where `file` points will not be changed.

Comment: the posted code really needs to be checking the returned value from calls to `fseek()` and `fread()` to assure the operations were successful.

Comment: regarding: `for(int i = 0; token != NULL; i++) {`  This will create problems.  Suggest: `int i = 0;;  while( i < 2048 && token ) {` and increment `i` at the end of the loop.  This will avoid any possibility of overflowing the array of pointers and will exit the loop when no more sentences to extract.

Comment: regarding: `for(int i = 0; i < 2048; i++)
        printf("%s", destination[i]);`  This will be trying to dereference all 2048 entries in the array `destination[]`  If there were less than 2048 sentences in the input file, then this will be dereferencing address 0.  The result will be a seg fault event.  suggest stopping when `destination[i] == NULL`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to be sure you dont exceed destination size. and -1 for null char.

```
 fread(*destination, sizeof(char), min(size_in_bytes, destinationSize - 1), file);
```

destination[i] doesnt end with null char. You cant use it as parameter of printf

```
for(int i = 0; i < 2048; i++)
    printf("%s", destination[i]); // can cause SEGFAULT
```

and another limit check for destination. i < 2048 should be added to for check.

```
for(int i = 0; token != NULL && i < 2048; i++) {
    destination[i] = token;
    token = strtok(NULL, ENDL);
}
```

Comment: I have resolved the issue - and there was no issue with the file reading code so your answer would appear to be incorrect

Comment: Added another issue

Comment: the function:  `fread()` does NOT NUL terminate the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that printf calls strlen in the background when you are using %s - switching to fputs fixes the issue

Comment: Rather than 'working around' the issue by fputs'ing a NULL pointer, you should probably check for a NULL prior to the printing (`if (destination[i] != NULL) { printf("%s", destination[i]); }`. You should also ensure that you don't split into more than 2048 tokens, as that's a whole additional list of issues.